# What is an instantiable "class" called in JavaScript other than an object?

Tags: javascript, oop, terminology

I have an object like this:

```
function Person() {}
```

What would you call it other than an object? Obviously it is not a class, but what is it? I am looking for a term that is not an object, because I want to specifically highlight the fact that you can create a new instance of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"`function Person() {}`" is a *constructor function* for a **type**. A value of `new Person()` would be an instance (or *object*) of **type** *Person*.

Comment: Good choice, that does sound good. I'll wait to see if anyone comes up with anything better. :)